# Scipy integration off by orders of magnitude

Tags: python, scipy

Below is a really simple example for calculating the area of a circle that integrates a series of small areas:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps, cumtrapz
r1 = 0.0
r2 = 1.0

area = np.pi*(r2**2 - r1**2)
print('Known area: '+str(area))

r = np.linspace(r1,r2,1000,endpoint=True)
dr = r[1]-r[0]
dA = 2.0*np.pi*r*dr
a_int = simps(y=dA)
print('Simps area: '+str(a_int))
a_int = simps(y=dA,x=r)
print('Simps area: '+str(a_int))
a_int = cumtrapz(y=dA)[-1]
print('Cumtrapz area: '+str(a_int))
a_int = cumtrapz(y=dA,x=r)[-1]
print('Cumtrapz area: '+str(a_int))
```

What confuses me is that in both the `simps` and `cumtrapz` methods, the result is orders of magnitudes off the known result when both `x` and `y` are passed to the method, but is otherwise correct when just `y` data is passed to the method.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious here. Can someone clarify why I am seeing errors of this magnitude?

Comment: the `simps` version should be `4 * simps(y=np.sqrt(1 - r**2), x=r)`. this is from the graphical interpretation of a quarter-circle. i have no idea how to interpret your attempt....

Comment: the integration shown in my example is pretty standard, take a circle and divide it up into thin strips of width dr such that the small area dA at a point r along the radius is 2*pi*r*dr where 2pi r is the circumference at radius r.

Comment: yes i understand that. but neither of  `x` and `y` should be differentials. they should be corresponding function values.

Answer (score 2):

The expression that you are approximating with [`scipy.integrate.simpson`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html) (née `simps`) is the definite integral

```
         r₂
   A =  ∫  2 π r dr
         r₁
```

The *integrand* is f(r) = 2 π r, so that is the function from which you should take the samples to be passed as the `y` parameter of `simpson`; don't multiply the samples by `dr`.  When you call `simpson`, pass the array `r` as the `x` parameter.  `simpson` takes care of multiplying the given samples by `dr`. (Instead of passing `x=r`, you could pass `dx=r[1] - r[0]`.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simpson


r1 = 0.0
r2 = 1.0

area = np.pi*(r2**2 - r1**2)
print(f'Known area:   {area}')

r = np.linspace(r1, r2, 1000, endpoint=True)
y = 2.0*np.pi*r

a_int = simpson(y=y, x=r)
print(f'Simpson area: {a_int}')
```

Output:

```
Known area:   3.141592653589793
Simpson area: 3.141592653589793
```

This also applies to [`numpy.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) and [`scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html) (née `cumtrapz`).